# Playing with DataKinds - Kind mis-match errors

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families, type-level-computation, data-kinds

I've been teaching myself about type-level programming and wanted to write a simple natural number addition type function. My first version which works is as follows:

```
data Z
data S n

type One = S Z
type Two = S (S Z)

type family Plus m n :: *
type instance Plus Z n = n
type instance Plus (S m) n = S (Plus m n)
```

So in GHCi I can do:

```
ghci> :t undefined :: Plus One Two
undefined :: Plus One Two :: S * (S * (S * Z))
```

Which works as expected. I then decided to try out the DataKinds extension by modifying the `Z` and `S` types to:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
```

And the Plus family now returns a `Nat` kind:

```
type family Plus m n :: Nat
```

The modified code compiles but the problem is I now get an error when testing it:

```
Kind mis-match
Expected kind `OpenKind', but `Plus One Two' has kind `Nat'
In an expression type signature: Plus One Two
In the expression: undefined :: Plus One Two
```

I've searched for a solution but Google has failed me. Does a solution exist or have I hit some limit of the language?

Comment: use `:kind! Plus One Two` in ghci.

Comment: I think in `undefined :: SomeType`, `SomeType` has to be of kind `*` only.

Comment: If you really want to carry around a type witness at runtime, you can use the standard [`Proxy` trick](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/tagged/0.4.4/doc/html/Data-Proxy.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think way you are testing is not correct. `undefined` can be of any type of kind `*` (I maybe wrong here).

Try this in ghci

```
ghci>:t (undefined :: 'Z)

<interactive>:1:15:
    Kind mis-match
    Expected kind `OpenKind', but `Z' has kind `Nat'
    In an expression type signature: Z
    In the expression: (undefined :: Z)
```

You can still get the type of `Plus One Two` by using `:kind!` in ghci

```
ghci>:kind! Plus One Two
Plus One Two :: Nat
= S (S (S 'Z))
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Surely though, Nat would be a subkind (is that a thing?) of *?

Comment: I don't think there is anything like subkind but I am no expert.

Comment: @TomSavage: no, `*` is more specific than it may seem: those are only [_lifted types_](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism-and-promotion.html).